# Question about reading int and String from array

Tags: c

I have two-dimensional arrays which contain the input from a file. I want to assign integers and strings from the array to different variables; the integer is set correctly, but the string is not working.

the input is like:

```
(1,2) apple 2 3 north
```

but all these information are inside:

```
char data[MAX_LINES][MAX_LEN];
```

I am trying to use sscanf to assign values:

```
sscanf(data[i],"(%d,%d) %8s %d %d %8s",&x,&y,type,&age,&hun,direction);
```

Code structure by ignoring unrelated code

```
    FILE *in_file = fopen(fileName,"r");
    char data[MAX_LINES][MAX_LEN];
    int x,y,age,hun;
    char type[10];
    char deriction[20];
    if(! in_file){
        printf("cannot read file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int line=0;
    while(!feof(in_file) && !ferror(in_file)){
        if(fgets(data[line],MAX_LEN,in_file) !=NULL ){
            char *check = strtok(data[line],d);
            
            line++;
        }
    }
    fclose(in_file);
    for(int i = 9; i<14;i++){
        sscanf(data[i],"(%d,%d) %8s %d %d %8s",&x,&y,type,&age,&hun,deriction);
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mre].

Comment: You should check the return value of `scanf()` to ensure that it's parsing the input correctly.

Comment: Unable to reproduce: https://ideone.com/6UVizD

Comment: Please show the declarations of all the variables you're reading into.

Comment: See [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/15168) for a discussion of why it is a bad idea to use `feof()` (or `ferror()`, or both) in a loop control.  Test the input function result directly, not the flags used by `feof()` and `ferror()`.

Comment: What is _magical_ about lines 9-13 that those are selected for printing???

Comment: BZS, What is `MAX_LEN`?   Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    //Data:
    char data[1][100] = {"(1,2) apple 2 3 north"};
    
    //Define variables:
    int x, y, age, hun;
    char type[10], direction[10];
    
    sscanf(data[0], "(%d,%d) %s %d %d %s", &x, &y, type, &age, &hun, direction);

    //Check by printing it out:
    printf("(%d,%d) %s %d %d %s\n", x, y, type, age, hun, direction);
    printf("x: %d\ny: %d\ntype: %s\nage: %d\nhun: %d\ndirection: %s", x, y, type, age, hun, direction);

    //Success:
    return 0;
}
```

If this doesn't work, then the problem might be the data in your array, `data`.

Answer (score 0):

You have the line `char *check = strtok(data[line],d);`.  You've not shown what `d` is, but unless it is a string with no characters in common with the input line, `strtok()` just mangled your stored data, zapping whatever is the first character from `d` with a null byte.  That means your `sscanf()` will fail because it isn't looking at the whole line.  If, perchance, you have `const char d[] = "\r\n";` or equivalent, this ceases to be relevant, beyond pointing out that you should show enough code to reproduce the problem.